# RunGHC gives "target ‘prog’ is not a module name or a source file"

Tags: haskell, raspberry-pi, ghc

I'm just starting to work through Real World Haskell, and have just gotten to the first example program. I'm running GHC on a Raspberry Pi, raspbian lite. The program, WC.hs, is

```
main = interact wordCount
    where wordCount input = show (length (lines input)) ++ "\n"
```

and you call a csv text file that looks like

```
Paris, France
Ulm, Germany
Auxerre, France
Brunswick, Germany
```

When I try to run this program as proscribed in the book,

```
runghc WC < quux.txt
```

I get the error

```
target ‘prog’ is not a module name or a source file
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I can't remember the exact syntax, but the error seems to suggest `runghc WC.hs < ...`

Comment: That gives me `<no location info>: error: can't find file: []

<no location info>: error: can't find file: "WC.hs"

<no location info>: error: can't find file: prog
`

I have a growing suspicion that my GHC installation is borked. I did have to install an old package to get it to work on Raspbian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my installation of GHC was imperfect. Due to the RPi's ARM architecture, and some odd decisions they've made to keep Raspbian backwards-compatible,  you currently have to make workarounds to install GHC. The first I tried was from [this](https://svejcar.dev/posts/2019/09/23/haskell-on-raspberry-pi-4/#solving-troubles-with-ghc) post, which worked well in GHCI, but didn't do well outside of it.

Luckily, since then, people more closely involved with GHC's development have taken an interest in making it ARM and RPi compatible, and created a healthier installation process (though still not fully package managed) [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/blog/20200515-ghc-on-arm.html).
After reinstalling GHC, the program worked.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you post suggest the file `WC.hs` is not in the directory you're in when running `runghc`.  The sequence of commands works on a normal system:

```
% cat <<EOF >WC.hs
heredoc> main = interact wordCount
    where wordCount input = show (length (lines input)) ++ "\n"
heredoc> EOF
% cat <<EOF >quux.txt
heredoc> Paris, France
Ulm, Germany
Auxerre, France
Brunswick, Germany
heredoc> EOF
% runghc WC.hs < quux.txt
Loaded package environment from /private/tmp/.ghc.environment.x86_64-darwin-8.6.4
4
```

So double check your directories and file names.

Comment: I'm definitely in the directory the .hs and .txt files live in. I can run ls with no modifiers and see them right there.